# angular material grid xs not working

Tags: angularjs, html, css, angularjs-material

```
<md-grid-list md-cols-lg="4" md-cols-sm="2" md-cols-xs="1" md-cols-md="2" md-gutter="3em" md-row-height='250px'>
       <md-grid-tile><div>one</div></md-grid-tile>
       <md-grid-tile><div>two</div></md-grid-tile>
       <md-grid-tile> <div>three</div> </md-grid-tile>
       <md-grid-tile>  <div>four</div></md-grid-tile>
 </md-grid-list>
```

This is working fine in sm , md and lg but not working in xs (extra small devices)

Comment: what about it is not working?

Comment: once it  reaches breakpoint, its not making to one column  it remains two only ,some error appering in console

Answer (score 0):

Well I've pasted your html and it's working on this [codepen](http://codepen.io/tuncelmert/pen/EWMVVo)

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-app="MyApp">
   <md-grid-list md-cols-lg="4" md-cols-sm="2" md-cols-xs="1" md-cols-md="2" md-gutter="3em" md-row-height='250px'>
      <md-grid-tile><div>one</div></md-grid-tile>
      <md-grid-tile><div>two</div></md-grid-tile>
      <md-grid-tile> <div>three</div> </md-grid-tile>
      <md-grid-tile>  <div>four</div></md-grid-tile>
   </md-grid-list>
</div>
```

What's the error you are getting?

**Update**

Since Material is strictly looking for md-cols attribute you need to define a `md-cols="[col number you want]"` as default and then use query definitons to change the value. Such as:

```
   <md-grid-list md-cols="4" md-cols-sm="2" md-cols-xs="1" md-cols-md="2">
   </md-grid-list>
```

please note that this default value will be affecting all the screen sizes you don't cover with queries.

Comment: Possibly unhandled rejection: md-grid-list: md-cols attribute was not found, or contained a non-numeric value,this was error i got

Comment: then just change `md-cols-xs="1"` to `md-cols="1"`, or any one of the media query definitions, but just one.